Is readline essentially a user mode line discipline?
The TTY terminal driver uses a line discipline to provide features like: line buffering of input, echoing of input to the terminal display, control character translation, etc. The bash shell uses the readline function for its input, and my understanding is that readline puts the terminal in raw mode, which disables the line discipline. So, does readline take over the line discipline's role in providing the features above, and is it fair to say that it's a user mode line discipline?

This feels like a "if my grandma had wheels, she'd be a bicycle" kinda thing. If the analogy works for whatever is you are trying to do, sure, use it. But if someone in your audience did object, would you point to this post and say that some random user on the internet said it's OK?

I’d say: if you moved the readline functionality into the kernel and surrounded it with the termios API, you’d have a line discipline.

Then you already have your answer, no?

First, termios is a very tight standard, actually very restrictive.  So it would actually not be possible to wrap readline in termios.  You'd have to make a new API and it would not be termios.   Second, termios is not necessary for and not part of the line discipline, it's just a standard way to talk to it.  And last, putting readline into the kernel, assuming you could even make a standard for it, would be bloat and a security risk, because it's overcomplicated and requires too much user level API interaction to make it work.  As is, putting it in the kernel just doesn't make sense.

Both of your points are not accurate, and you seem to be confused about the relationship between termios and the line discipline.

Yes and no.
Yes, readline serves the same (but enhanced) user facing functionality as the cooked mode line discipline.
However, it is not a line discipline.  There are two of those, cooked and raw.
Readline is not a line discipline, as the line discipline is implemented in the low level kernel I/O drivers.  Readline is a user mode program that suffers from user mode scheduling issues just like any other program.  The kernel's implementation of the line discipline is scheduled as part of a low level driver and is not similar in implementation to readline.
What distinguishes a line discipline from readline is that readline is a library and a line discipline is a mode in the kernel driver that is set by a bit in the tty settings.  Setting these settings were standardized and formalized in the POSIX termios library, and the API is now baked into the kernel.  (The line discipline is in the kernel and predates termios; termios is just the standard API that sets it.)
Readline is not a line discipline.  Readline uses the raw line discipline, and does not make its own.  (Unless you move it into a kernel driver at least; but that's not likely, as it is not standard.  Readline doesn't even follow its own standard, there are multiple conflicting implementations.)

Well the Q does say "user mode line discipline", which it wouldn't be if it was moved into the kernel.

Line discipline is not user mode.  It's a kernel thing.  That's what the label means.
